# Why is it that sometimes my web application does not work on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, authentication, session, cookies

I have a web application that uses login and sessions (cookies).  Why is it that sometimes, when the iPhone is going slow with the 3G network (super super slow), the iphone doesn't see the cookies?

Cookies don't work when the iPhone network is slow!!!

Comment: It's unlikely that the iPhone frameworks know prior to sending the request that the network is slow, and so exclude the cookies. If you can provide logs that prove this, or a small sample application to reproduce the problem, then someone here may be able to help. If you can do that, though, I also encourage you to file a bug with Apple (http://bugreport.apple.com/).

Answer (score 0):

When in the slow network, is it still 3G or is it EDGE/GPRS (2G) network? If cookie behavior is different between 3G and EDGE/GPRS, it might be your carrier's responsibility. You carrier might delete header in HTTP request/response. You'd better have both client-side and server-side log to verify this.